# Spring consuming-ws: Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: web-services, spring-ws, maven-jaxb2-plugin, consuming, connectionexception

I run my spring ws application downloaded from official spring.io web site, and it gives me following error [image: error from console]

Please help me, cant understand what's problem? 
P.s: It is consuming web service, building on maven,
and "http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx?WSDL" works if call via browser